# Polymorphism Without Indirect Jumps?

Tags: oop, assembly, polymorphism

When I learned MIPS assembly a few months ago, a question popped into my head that I forgot to ask then, so I thought I'd ask it now:

#### Is it possible to implement polymorphism *without* indirect jump instructions? If so, how?

(Indirect jumps are the "jump register" instructions, e.g. `jr $t0` in MIPS or `jmp EAX` in x86.)

One such solution I came up with is self-modifying code, but I'm curious as to whether polymorphism (and so OOP) would be possible by any other means.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use indirect jumps?

Comment: @Sparafusile: I'm not sure if you actually read my first sentence...

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at, is, why did you single this one feature out for exclusion? And what exactly do indirect jumps have to do with polymorphism? I started to answer your question, but, when I boiled it all down, my answer consisted of "Yes. Just don't use them."

Comment: @Sparafusile: Well, I started thinking about how I would actually *implement* a polymorphic object by hand (vtable and all), and the conclusion I came down to was that it was impossible without the ability to do an indirect jump. That seemed like a very interesting conclusion, and I'm wondering if that's correct -- and if not, then how else could you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer to your question would be to write your program (and possible assembler) in such a way that all method calls can be resolved at runtime thus negating the need for a lookup table. I'm going to assume you're talking about passing a subclass to a function that was designed for a superclass and it is therefore impossible to implement this optimization.

Eliminating the lookup, I think, is outside the scope of your question so I'm going to suggest replacements for the `jmp <reg>` instruction (sorry, I only know x86).

- You can execute a `call <mem>` on a memory
  address (isn't this how you would do
  it using a lookup table?)
- You can execute a `call <reg>` on a register
  (not entirely different from the jmp
  , but does answer your question)
- You can `jmp <mem>` if you wanted, but
  that's not all that different from `jmp <reg>`

All of these are possible and solve your problem, but are all alike. I guess this illustrates my confusion on why you would want to do what you're asking. You have to have some way to choose which method to call (the vtable) and some way to transfer execution to the method (using `jmp` or `call`).

The only other possible way to do this would be to fiddle with the register that is used to point to the next command in the execution chain (`EIP` in x86). Whether you can or should is another question. I suppose if you were intimately knowledgeable of the architecture and weren't worried about it changing you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

**You may want to consider changing your question however**

Consider this C++ code where `Derived` is obviously polymorphic (yes, I didn't delete the object):

```cpp
class Base
{
    public: int foo(){ return 1; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public: int foo(){ return 2; };
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived();

    return b->foo();    //Returns 1
}
```

The assembly generated by gcc is

```
main:
.LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    _Znwm
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZN4Base3fooEv
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

As you can see there is no indirect jump/call.

That's because **polymorphism** is not the point here (though it is necessary), **virtual methods** are.

Then the answer becames

### No

If by indirect jump/call you means *every technique that use a runtime value for computing the target of the jump/call* (so including things like `ret`, `call []`, `call reg`, `jr`, `jalr`).

Consider this source

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public: virtual int foo(){ return 1; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public: int foo(){ return 2; };
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
    public: int foo(){ return 3; };
};



int main()
{
    int a;
    Base* b = 0; //don't remember the header for std::nullptr right now...

    std::cin >> a;

    if (a > 241)
        b = new Derived();
    else 
        b = new Derived2();

    return b->foo();    //Returns what?
}
```

The result depends on the user input, an archetypal runtime value, so must be the called routine and no static address would do.

Note that in this case the compiler could use a jump toward calls with static address (as either `Derived2::foo` or `Derived::foo` is called) but this is not in general possible (you may have multiple object files without the source, you may have an aliasing pointer, the pointer `b` could be set by an external library, and so on).